# How do you print C dynamic array contents from dbx?

Tags: dbx

How do you print C dynamic array contents from dbx?

i tried print aj[2..10:1] but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just say "print aj"
Dbx will use dynamic information to print the array.

Are you asking about array slicing syntax in C?

You could try this:

(dbx) print a[1..1]
a[1..1] = 
[1] = -17334836